# How does one interact with an OpenAPI-defined webhook?

Tags: webhooks, openapi

Reading the OpenAPI webhook spec, I'm having trouble understanding how would I implement / interact with an OpenAPI defined webhook. My main sources are:

- https://spec.openapis.org/oas/latest.html#openapi-object (spec, `webhooks` field)
- https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/examples/v3.1/webhook-example.yaml (example)

Let's take a look at this example (I trimmed the irrelevant parts)

```yaml
openapi: 3.1.0
webhooks:
  newPet:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/Pet"
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Return a 200 status to indicate that the data was received successfully
```

My questions:

- Does this mean when this `newPet` event happens (what this event means, is implementation detail according to the spec, as far as I can see), this server may send a `POST` request with a `Pet` body, and expects a response with `200` status code?

  - If **no**,

    - Then what does this mean?
  - If **yes**,

    - **To what URL** is this request being sent to?
    - Can the user of this API somehow **register** a URL where this request should be sent to?
    - If the user of this API no longer wishes to receive `POST` requests related to the `newPet` event, how do they **unsubscribe**?
    - Is the **protocol** still HTTP (I'm 99% sure, just to be safe)?

Comment: OpenAPI callbacks, which continue to be supported in OpenAPI Spec 3.1, provide a way to specify the client's server URL. Webhooks is similar but allows you to skip that part and assume it's handled elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean when this `newPet` event happens (what this event means, is implementation detail according to the spec, as far as I can see), this server may send a `POST` request with a `Pet` body, and expects a response with `200` status code?

Yes.

> To what URL is this request being sent to?

This URL is defined somewhere outside the API. For example, the API vendor can provide a developer portal where developers can subscribe to the webhooks they need and configure the target URLs.

> Can the user of this API somehow register a URL where this request should be sent to?

See above.

> If the user of this API no longer wishes to receive POST requests related to the newPet event, how do they unsubscribe?

See above. Webhook subscription management is supposed to happen somewhere outside the API.

> Is the protocol still HTTP (I'm 99% sure, just to be safe)?

OpenAPI Specification does not mention this, but it's safe to assume HTTP or HTTPS. Some vendors limit outgoing webhook URLs to HTTPS only for security reasons.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. So does this mean, that this is not really meant to be used for codegen, more for documentation purposes?

Comment: I guess webhook definitions can be used to generate server-side boilerplate code for sending outgoing webhooks. There's an [existing feature request](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/6689) to support webhooks in the [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/).

Answer (score 1):

The following sentence of the [OpenAPI 3.1 specifications description of the webhooks section](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.1.0.md#oasWebhooks) helped clarify the difference between webhooks and callbacks for me (emphasis mine):

> Closely related to the callbacks feature, this section describes **requests initiated other than by an API call**, for example by an out of band registration.